# Different column widths under a multicolumn prevent appropriate centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, multicolumn

How can I center the two columns inside the multicolumn?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},
         input-decimal-markers={.},
         group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4
}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
\begin{tabular}{cc
|
S[table-format=1.0]
S[table-format=3.0]
|
S[table-format=4.0]
|
}
\cline{3-5}
& &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{has breast cancer} & \\
& &    {yes} & {no} & {total} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{screened positive}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{yes} & 7 & 70 & 77     \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{no}& 1 & 922 & 923   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}
& total & 8 & 992 & 1,000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},
         input-decimal-markers={.},
         group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4
}
```

**Edit** (in response to @Bernard 's comment):

I added the vertical line and edited one of the column specifications and data so that the columns should be the same width. The result changes the thrust of my question though not the goal. I need to ask why the columns have such different widths. The lack of centering seems to be a side effect.

[image]

Modified MWE:

```
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
\begin{tabular}{cc
|
%S[table-format=1.0]
S[table-format=3.0]
|
S[table-format=3.0]
| % extra vertical line
S[table-format=4.0]
|
}
\cline{3-5}
& &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{has breast cancer} & \\
& &    {yes} & {no} & {total} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{screened positive}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{yes} & 7 & 70 & 77     \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{no}& 1 & 922 & 923   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}
%& total & 8 & 992 & 1,000 \\
& total & 800 & 992 & 1,000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add a verticel rule  between the two columns under the multicolumn, you'll see they *are* centred. It s the lack of vertical rule, that make them look uncentred, due to the difference of their widths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using `\makebox` one can force the entries `{yes}` and `{no}` to each fill up half the available space.  Note, the outer `{}` is needed around `\makebox` for some reason.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},
         input-decimal-markers={.},
         group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4
}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\tempdima}{has breast cancer}% compute width needed
\addtolength{\tempdima}{-2\tabcolsep}% minus default column sep

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
\begin{tabular}{cc
|
S[table-format=1.0]
S[table-format=3.0]
|
S[table-format=4.0]
|
}
\cline{3-5}
& &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{has breast cancer} & \\
& &   {\makebox[0.5\tempdima]{yes}} & {\makebox[0.5\tempdima]{no}} & {total} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{screened positive}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{yes} & 7 & 70 & 77     \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{no}& 1 & 922 & 923   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}
& total & 8 & 992 & 1,000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: makebox in taqbular]

Comment: This works even when the text "has breast cancer" is replaced by something much shorter than "yes ... no". So I should be able to automate it with a macro for other similar tables. Thank you.

Comment: @Mic0 -  Yup.  I tested it by comparing it with using @{}.  Will edit solution. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: The "some reason" for having to place curly braces around the two `\makebox` instructions comes from the fact that the default column type for both columns is `S`. *Without* the curly braces, `siunitx` will try to parse the material, which cannot be the intent. With the curly braces, the material will simply be centered. (Of course, given that the boxes take up the full width of the respective columns, centering the columns has no further effect.)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},
         input-decimal-markers={.},
         group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4
}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}% for the vertical padding
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}

\cline{3-5}
& &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{has breast cancer} &  \\
& &  {yes} & {no} & {total} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{screened positive}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{yes} & 7 & 70 & 77     \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}        &                
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{no}& 1 & 922 & 923   \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}
& total & 8 & 992 & 1,000 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't do what I need. Without the `siunitx` `S` option it centers the numbers rather than right justifying them in a centered column. The two columns beneath the multicolumn aren't centered there. And there's an extra vertical rule. I added the image that compiled from your code.